# Removing await doesn't reflect next code lines after to execute

Tags: c#

As far as i know if there is no await keyword in async method then method continues without waiting on Task therefore removing await keyword should act to continue and show `Boom` message in console immediately not awaiting on Run method to finish. Nevertheless when i removed await in Main here:

```
await new Runner().Run(date);
```

word Boom still waits and shows in console after Run is finished. Can anyone explain? I know that because in SomeFunction there is connection to database which tries to connect and after few seconds giving error to console and i always see error first and after that line Boom is reached.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Task aa = new Runner().Run(date);
    Console.WriteLine("Boom");
}

class Runner
{
    public async Task Run(DateTime date)
    {
       try
       {          
          Console.WriteLine("Runner runs");
          await SomeFunction();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without await it still runs the method, it just doesn't wait for it to finish before continuing. When you await, you're telling it not to continue with the method you're in until the awaited task is done. Not awaiting will not stop the method from running if you call it.

Comment: Why Then "Boom" doesn't show immediately as first? Run executes but since not await on it Boom should be immediately shown in console window before error appear from Run.

Comment: beacause when you await it the code stops and waits for the method, if you dont await it it continues in the background, and updates when its done, but your compiler has already moved on from the call

Comment: when there is await Run then it's clear Boom will be shown after Run is completed but when i remove await on Run Boom should appear as first one because Main continue.. However either there is await Run() or just Run() Boom is always executed at the end..

Comment: Task aa = new Runner().Run(date);
    Console.WriteLine("Boom");   switch these two lines you have an await in runner, since your calling it first, it awaits before you call boom

Comment: you said that if i have as you shown Boom should appear as first right, but it doesn't..

Comment: if you switch those two lines. it should

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182593/discussion-between-dinodin2-and-princeofravens).

Answer (score -1):

The only explanation for that behavior is that `SomeFunction` is not in fact asynchronous.  It is apparently running synchronously, and seemingly returning an already completed `Task` whenever it finishes.  It shouldn't do that if it's going to return a `Task`, it should either clearly be a synchronous method and return the result directly, or actually do its work asynchronously, and you should treat this behavior as a bug in that method.

Comment: so you mean even if i have in Main: new Runner().Run(date) (without await) ; Console.Writeline("Boom") this not means that Boom will be executed immediatly because Run could be still blocking main thread, same thread Boom want to be executed?

Comment: @DinoDin2 Yes.  It shouldn't, but if implemented incorrectly, it certainly can.